# Android layout above issue

Tags: android, layout

iam designin new app , and at some part i need two layouts on top of each other , but not using arndroid:orientation , insted of that i need to use layout_above/layout_below , but it says to me is a invalid parameter for LinearLayout here is the code

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/menu"
        android:gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/t1"  
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="#DDDDDD">

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/t2"  
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="#DDDDDD">

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/t3"  
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_above="@id/t1"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="#DDDDDD">

            </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

so linear layouts t1 and t2 are next to each other witch is fine , but i want linearlayout t3 above t1

Comment: As Daniel said, LinearLayout is probably not the best option. RelativeLayout or GridLayout is more likely a better option in your case. It would be easier to help if you could post an image (wireframe/ascii-art) of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android:layout_above/layout_below are only allowed on RelativeLayout, use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and it will work. Ex:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/below_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rev_arrow">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        android:id="@+id/above_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's a good tutorial on layouts:
http://android.programmerguru.com/android-relativelayout-example/

Comment: There is almost never any need to nest RelativeLayouts. It will only add complexity and rendering time.
Also, consider using GridLayout.